# Can I use functions with LaTeX?

Tags: programming

I am writing out equations and a lot of my equations have parameters changed but the basic structure is repeated.

I have reduced the problem to a hypothetical example  as follows.

```
    if (condition ==2) {
        p = 2*(x^2)
    } else if (condition ==3) {
        p = 3*(x^3)
    }
    
    print(p)
```

Please note that storing and retrieving are both required features. I am not certain if it is possible with `LaTeX`, but I believe the authors of `LaTeX` (being computer scientists) must have thought about it.

Comment: Do you mean something like `\newcommand\nxton[1]{p = #1 x^{#1} }` which is then used as: `$\nxton{2}$` ?

Comment: Another innocent mind drawn to the black hole of TeX programming.

Comment: Do you mean something like `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\condition{3}
\ifnum\condition=2\relax\def\p{2*(x^2)}\else
  \ifnum\condition=3\relax\def\p{3*(x^3)}\fi
\fi
\detokenize\expandafter{\p}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 5):

If you can use LuaLaTeX instead of either pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX, it's straightforward to set up Lua functions along the lines of the example you gave as well as TeX "wrapper macros" that call the Lua functions with the required inputs.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function pfunc ( cond , x )
   local p = 0
   x = tonumber ( x )
   if cond == "2" then
      p = 2*x^2 
   elseif cond == "3" then
      p = 3*x^3 
   end
   tex.sprint ( p ) 
end
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\pfunc[2]{\directlua{ pfunc ( \luastring{#1} , \luastring{#2})}}

\begin{document}
\pfunc{2}{2}, \pfunc{3}{3}, \pfunc{1}{111}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure from the OP whether he wanted the computations done or only typeset...

Comment: @jfbu - I'm not entirely sure either. The expression "the storing and the retrieving are both the features which [are] required" led me to believe that the function must actually do something, rather than just be printed out. Let's see if the OP weighs in and clarifies his/her objective.

Comment: perhaps he indeed wants to evaluate the expression and store the value in a `p` to be "retrieved" later if needed. As you say, only OP can clarify!

Comment: Hi Jfbu, you are right. I am looking at the function actually doing something rather than just retrieving.

Comment: @user2714795 - Please give an example or two of what you mean by "actually doing something".

Comment: Hi, It means if I put x =2 then it computes and gives me 3*2*2*2 = 24. So 24 should be printed instea of only 3 *x^3. I am not sure if this is possible but given it has load store capability i believe it should be there somehow.

Comment: @user2714795 - In my answer, if you type `\pfunc{3}{2}` anywhere between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, you *will* get `24`.

Answer (score 0):

With [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package, you can write the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \MyFunc {m} {
  \FpCompareTF {\cond} = {2} {
    \TlSet \p {\FpEval{2*(#1)^2}}
  } {
    \FpCompareTF {\cond} = {3} {
      \TlSet \p {\FpEval{3*(#1)^3}}
    } { } 
  }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\def\cond{2} \MyFunc{5} \p
\def\cond{3} \MyFunc{5} \p

\end{document}
```

[image]